# How to enable macro and auto-login from MS Access to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a query in MS Access that accesses tables in our SQL Server DB. The Access DB lives on a Dev server, and the SQL Server DB is on another server. Every time anyone opens the Access DB on their personal machine, and tries to run the query for the first time, two undesired events are occurring:

1. Message appears below the menus: "Security Warning: Certain content in the database has been disabled", and a button reading "Options...". You have to click on that button, and select "Enable this content". I figure this is because of a VB script macro the previous developer put in the Access file, which is fine, so I want that macro always enabled. I figure the correct procedure to do this is to open the Trust Center, select "Add new Location", input the path to the Access DB on the Dev server, and check "Allow Trusted Locations on my network (not recommended)". This is a secure network, so may I safely ignore the "not recommended" part?
2. Once the content has been enabled, if you try to run the query, you get a "connection failed:" popup that reads "Microsoft SQL Server Login" at the top. Click okay, and a dialog appears for the SQL Server login, with only the non-Windows username (grayed out), and no password. I know the non-Windows credentials to log in, and I'd like it connect to the SQL Server DB automatically whenever this Access database file is opened, rather than having to log in every time someone runs the query for the first time.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1 is irrelevant, you've done what you should.

Point 2:

On the DEV server:

- Add an [ODBC entry](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879308(v=sql.105).aspx) that points on your SQL server database, you should choose the user password authentication method and enter your credentials there.
- In the Access aplication, remove existing linked table and [add them again](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-A5A3B4EB-57B9-45A0-B732-77BC6089B84E) using the ODBC entry you previously created

---

If your queries are passthrough and not from linked tables, add the following code in a VBA module and run it (F5)

```
Private Sub CheckPTQ()

    Dim qdf As QueryDef

    For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If qdf.Type = dbQSQLPassThrough or qdf.Connect<> ""  Then
            debug.print qdf.connect 
            'qdf.Connect = "new connect"
        End If
    Next

end sub
```

At first run it will print the connection strings of your passthrough queries. Analyze them and change what's need to be changed, if you need some inspiration, [the bible is there](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

When you're ready with your connection string, uncomment the following line :

```
'qdf.Connect = "new connect"
```

and adapt the *new connect* with your new con string, and run the code again to assign it to all your queries

Comment: Point 1's taken care of, but with point 2, looking further I'm not sure the linked tables are involved. I see that the query is actually querying another "Pass-through" query. Looking at that pass-through query, I can't see anything in its properties that says where it's pulling its data from. The object properties only say that its a SQL pass-through query. Its sql reads "select * from tEmployee"; tEmployee is a table in the SQL Server DB, but again I don't know how the query knows that.

Comment: @Cmaso, ok worst case scenario but you can try the trick in my edited query